# Best way to implement scripted abilities using inheritance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement active unit abilities for a turn-based tactics game: click a button on the UI, have an effect on the battlefield/on another unit.

- I need to be able to attach a variable number of abilities to a unit.
- I would like to have abilities inherit from a base class with a `ActivateAbility()` function which is overridden for each distinct ability.
- I would like to be able to attach these abilities to a unit's prefab in the Unity editor, which I think means implementing abilities as `MonoBehavior` or `ScriptableObject`.

I had originally planned to put a `List<AbilityBase>` field in the unit script, and then fill the list with the unit's abilities (inherited from `AbilityBase`, which inherits from `MonoBehavior`) in each unit's prefab. But, that results in the abilities being treated as `AbilityBase` types due to serialization.

I then thought to try using [SerializeReference] on the list, but that doesn't support classes inherited from `MonoBehavior`.

I also thought to try implementing the abilities as `GameObjects` that are children of the unit itself and have the appropriate ability script, but I can't figure out a way to extract the relevant component while giving it the appropriate type: I can only get it as the `abilityBase` type.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [C# Delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/). Its probabbly a big change of paradigm but I think its the best approach to what you want.